# How to check the date and time is correct in offline Application Xamarin.Forms for both Android and iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms

If User disable the settings in Android - **Date and Time -> Use Network Provider Time** then user can alter the date and time.
Same in iOS too. How to check it is altered.

I'm getting the date from `DateTime.Now()` need to verify it.

Comment: if you're offline then there is nothing you can do about it

Comment: thank you @Jason, so any other way by which we can get Date Time whenever the app is connected to internet and get the date time and later just verifying the new value with time elapsed from stored value from internet.

Comment: yes, connect to a server and request the current time.  You could create your own service for this, or there are numerous existing services that will do this

Comment: Yes, I'm aware with the first portion of my statement above but I'm looking for second portion that is checking the datetime is correct just by comparing with stored date time from Internet whenever the network is available.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple workaround about getting *GMT time* online,
You can create a **Webrequest** and get GMT time in **response.Headers[Date]** and transfer it to local time based on your location.

**code behind:**

```
public string GetWebTime()
{
    WebRequest request = null;
    WebResponse response = null;
    WebHeaderCollection headerCollection = null;
    string datetime = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        request = WebRequest.Create("https://www.bing.com");
        request.Timeout = 3000;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        response = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        headerCollection = response.Headers;
        foreach (var h in headerCollection.AllKeys)
        {if (h == "Date")
            { datetime = headerCollection[h]; }
        }

        return datetime;

    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        return datetime;


    }
    finally {
        if (request != null)
        { request.Abort(); }
        if (response != null)
        { response.Close(); }
        if (headerCollection != null)
        {headerCollection.Clear(); }

    }
          

}
private void onButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myLabel.Text = GetWebTime();  
}
```

**result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the Answer, I have adapted the same already with NTP server, I can get it whenever the network is connected(for a user its difficult to be online throughout the usage). But My concern is how to check the given time at particular transition is correct. I thought of work around that compares the given time with the stored time from NTP server/ Web request through ElapsedTime.